# Flipping The Pairs

Tags: python

The program asks for a number and then prints out all the positive integer values from 1 up to the number. However, the order of the numbers is changed so that each pair or numbers is flipped. That is, 2 comes before 1, 4 before 3 and so forth. For example:

```
Please type in a number: 6
2
1
4
3
6
5
```

```
num = int(input("Please type in a number: "))
r = 2
t = 1


while True:
    if t >= num:
        break
    print(r)
    print(t)
    r += 2
    t += 2
```

The code works fine with even numbers but then struggles with odd numbers. For example with the input 5 the result should be:

```
Please type in a number: 5
2
1
4
3
5
```

But instead my output comes out as:

```
Please type in a number: 5
2
1
4
3
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do a simple change to your exiting code like below

```
num = int(input("Please type in a number: "))
r = 2
t = 1

while True:
    if t >= num:
        if num % 2 != 0:
            print(r-1)  # Display the last odd number
        break
    print(r)
    print(t)
    r += 2
    t += 2
```

The output will come as desired

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your own example, when `num` is odd and `t == num`, for example when `num` is `5` and `t` becomes `5`, then the loop simply exits without executing for the 3rd time. If the expected output is to output `5` instead of `6` (because there is nothing to "flip"), you can simply do `print(num)` if `num` is odd. However this is inconsistent with the `num=6` case as the fifth output is different, so I would recommend you double-check this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there will be several solutions, but a simple fix is here:

```
num = 5 # assigned for simple testing
r = 2
t = 1


while t <= num:
    if t != num:  # if t == num, skip the below line
        print(r)
    print(t)
    r += 2
    t += 2
```

An one-liner example:

```
print(sorted(range(1, num+1), key=lambda x: x + 2 * (x % 2)))
```

With list comprehension:

```
def fn(x):
    return x + 2 * (x % 2) - 1

print([x if x==num and num%2 else fn(x) for x in range(1, num+1)])
```

More readable version of the above example:

```
output = [x + 2 * (x % 2) - 1 for x in range(1, num+1)]
if num % 2:
    output[-1] = num
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `print(r)` only when `r <= num`, and move the `t > num` check after it:

```
num = int(input("Please type in a number: "))
r = 2
t = 1

while True:
    if r <= num:
        print(r)
    if t > num:
        break
    print(t)
    r += 2
    t += 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works

```
number = int(input("Please type in a number: "))
 
n = 1
while n + 1 <= number:
    print(n + 1)
    print(n)
    n += 2
 
if n <= number:
    print(n)
```